# Not able to find React code in Laravel/React project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I don't know how to start to explain and I know it sounds weird but I have Laravel project in which react is integrated. I don't have much knowledge about Laravel but I found that react code must be in resources/assets/js. But the project which I have there is no such folder is there.

There are chunk files that belong to react js, but there is no such specific react code I found. Does anyone have any idea why there are chunk files but not JavaScript files?

ProjectApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Presets/vue-stubs/webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

ProjectApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Presets/react-stubs/webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

ProjectApp/Modules/SuperCache/webpack.mix.js (In this folder there is package.json but when I am doing npm install and run it is throwing me an error)

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-merge-manifest');

mix.setPublicPath('../../public').mergeManifest();

mix.js(__dirname + '/Resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js/supercache.js')
    .sass( __dirname + '/Resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css/supercache.css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: "react code must be in resources/assets/js" this is no true, this is just the default location, you can put the code anywhere you want.

Comment: "There are chunk files that belong to react js, but there is no such specific react code I found." This does not make any sense to me at all.

Comment: @AndySong, I have a food app project which builds on laravel and React (PWA). When I run it with xamp localhost and the content which are showing on the localhost web page and try to do a global search in the project, I found the content in the chunk file. So I am confused where the code exists actually. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: what's your `webpack.mix.js` look like

Comment: @AndySong, I updated my question. I found these webpack.mix.js files.

Comment: @AndySong, this is the folder structure of Modules that exists with my main project: http://prntscr.com/u39sav

Any idea how can I find actual code?